# Firebase show data in select form - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show data in select form, from table heroes and "nombre" 
this is a name of client.

[image]

In my second table I want to show them while adding products to 
attribute clients to them.

[image]

Can any one help me to this? I'm new to angular :)

heroes.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroesService } from '../../services/heroes.service';
import { HeroeModel } from '../../models/heroe.model';
import {AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: HeroeModel[] = [];
  cargando = false;

  constructor(private heroesService: HeroesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cargando = true;
    this.heroesService.getHeroes().subscribe(resp => {
      this.heroes = resp;
      this.cargando = false;
    });
  }

  borrarHeroe(heroe: HeroeModel, index: number) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Uwaga!',
      text: `Czy chcesz trwale usunąć kontrahenta ${heroe.nombre}?`,
      type: 'warning',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true
    }).then(resp => {
      if (resp.value) {
        this.heroesService.deleteHeroe(heroe.id).subscribe(resp => {
          this.heroes.splice(index, 1);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

add-products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ADDProductsModel } from 'src/app/models/add-products.model';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { HeroesComponent } from 'src/app/pages/heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroeComponent } from 'src/app/pages/heroe/heroe.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-products',
  templateUrl: './add-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-products.component.css']
})
export class ADDProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  ADDProducts: ADDProductsModel = new ADDProductsModel();

  constructor(
    private ProductsService: ProductsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (id !== 'new') {
      this.ProductsService.getADDProducts(id).subscribe((resp: ADDProductsModel) => {
        this.ADDProducts = resp;
        this.ADDProducts.id = id;
      });
    }
  }

  guardar(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) {
      console.log('Nieprawidłowy format');
      return;
    }

    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Ładowanie',
      text: 'Trwa zapis...',
      type: 'info',
      allowOutsideClick: false
    });

    Swal.showLoading();

    let peticion: Observable<any>;

    if (this.ADDProducts.id) {
      peticion = this.ProductsService.actualizarADDProducts(this.ADDProducts);
    } else {
      peticion = this.ProductsService.crearADDProducts(this.ADDProducts);
    }

    peticion.subscribe(resp => {
      Swal.fire({
        title: this.ADDProducts.number,
        text: 'Dodano pomyślnie',
        type: 'success'
      });
    });
    console.log(form);
    console.log(this.ADDProducts);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: That I don't know how to download data to fill form to another component :( I have been trying to deal with this for hours.

Comment: You can use `@input` and `@output ` directive, for component interaction. You can send data to child component using `@input `and from child to parent you can send event emmiter using `@output`. Alternatively, you can use rxJS Subject too.. in your case you can consider your two components heros and add-item interaction with this approach.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda will it work with Firebase?

Comment: Yes, first you need to get all data from firebase and then pass data to component property, and that data again used as input data for child component, `<child- cmp [childData]="dataFromFirebase">` this is your child component. And in child component get data like this.. `@input('childData') childPropData;` and then you can use data in html like `{{ childPropData.fieldName}}`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda when i'm using <child- cmp [childData]="dataFromFirebase">
in child component I can see parent component https://i.imgur.com/tGYltk6.jpg not data from {{heroe.nombre}}

Comment: better screen https://imgur.com/kmjONzA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **First,** Consider Parent-Child model of communication in component interaction. For ease I am not going to include any firebase part here. I assume you are working with firebase Data very fine.

Now Your problem is how to send data back from child to parent so here is your solution.

**Complete solution is found here in** [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrwbrz)

- **app.component.html**

  ```
   <div>
        <span > Name comes form child in Parent Component </span>
        <select>
            <option> Select Name </option>    
            <option *ngFor="let item of nameFromChild"> {{item}} </option>
        </select>
   </div>
  ```
- **app.component.ts**

  ```
   export class AppComponent  {
          nameFromChild: string[] = []; // your property.
          /*
              nameFromChildFun() is called when there is data emitted from child-component. 
              @parms ='nameFromChild' : gets parameter from child using $event from app.component.html.
          */
          nameFromChildFun(nameFromChild){
                 this.nameFromChild.push(nameFromChild); //name pushes to property. and displaying in select tag using *ngFor. 
          }
   }
  ```
- **child.component.html**

  ```
   <input type ="text" [(ngModel)]="name"> <br><br>
   <button (click)="sendNameToParent(name)"> Add Name to Parent </button>
  ```
- **child.component.ts**

  ```
   import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

   export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
          @Output() nameFromChild = new EventEmitter();
          // nameFromChild is passed in app.component.html in <app-child (nameFromChild)="nameFromChildFun($event)

          sendNameToParent(name){
               this.nameFromChild.emit(name); // emitting value to parent.
          }
   }
  ```
- **Now when user clicks** in childComponent`s addNameToParent button then, call your firebase service here to Save ot Update data first and then load those data in parent app.component.

Comment: The problem is that after doing your code nothing shows up in dropdown form :(

Comment: I don't have any idea at this moment what I'm doing wrong ....

Comment: What have you been tried? And have you checked stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, and after implementing your code nothing shows up in a component that data should be shown up.